# Incorrect ES future open data from CME?

Tags: futures, market-data, ohlc

I was trying to validate some intraday ES future data. However, it looks like even the CME official is incorrect.

Let's take 2022-01-19 as an example

- CME shows the open price for MAR 22 is 4577.75 ([link](https://www.cmegroup.com/markets/equities/sp/e-mini-sandp500.settlements.html#tradeDate=01%2F19%2F2022))
  [image]
- If you look at their intraday chart (link from [here](https://www.cmegroup.com/markets/equities/sp/e-mini-sandp500.quotes.html)), the price around 8:30 is well above 4577.75
  [image]

Does anyone have any thoughts? How is the open price determined?

Comment: @noob2 Thank you so much! That makes sense. I'm able to find the correct data by looking at the day before.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The emini open for day T refers to the start of trading at 6pm NY time (5pm chicago) the night before (day T-1). The trading stops at 5pm NY time and then just one hour later trading for the next day starts. Historically the Big S&P contracts started trading at 9:30 am (8:30 chicago) but these contracts no longer trade. I used to write down the open for the Big S&P every day but I lost this data point with the demise of the Big S&P contract in 2021. (I suppose that is a disadvantage of having a contract that trades nearly 24 hours a day).

You can see in the graph on the extreme left that the emini starts at 5pm of jan 18 at 4577.75 then dips slightly (red) to a little under 4576 before recovering (green) to above 4576. The value 4577.75 is considered the "open" for the jan 19 trading.

Comment: Thank you so much!